# How to fast calculate the normalized l1 and l2 norm of a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, time-complexity

I have  a matrix **X** that has **n** column data vectors in **d** dimensional space.
Given a vector **xj**, **v[j]** is its **l1** norm (the summation of all **abs(xji)**), **w[j]** is the square of its **l2** norm (the summation of all **xji^2**), and **pj[i]** is the combination of entries divided by **l1** and **l2** norm. Finally, I need the outputs: **pj, v, w** for subsequet applications.

```
// X = new double [d*n]; is the input.
double alpha = 0.5;
double *pj = new double[d];
double *x_abs = new double[d];
double *x_2 = new double[d];
double *v = new double[n]();
double *w = new double[n]();
for (unsigned long j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        jm = j*m;
        jd = j*d;
        for (unsigned long i=0; i<d; ++i) {
            x_abs[i] = abs(X[i+jd]);
            v[j] += x_abs[i];
            x_2[i] = x_abs[i]*x_abs[i];
            w[j] += x_2[i];    
        }
        for (unsigned long i=0; i<d; ++i){
            pj[i] = alpha*x_abs[i]/v[j]+(1-alpha)*x_2[i]/w[j];     
        }

   // functionA(pj){ ... ...}  for subsequent applications
} 
// functionB(v, w){ ... ...} for subsequent applications
```

My above algorithm takes **O(nd)** Flops/Time-complexity, can any one help me to speed up it by using building-functoin or new implementation in C++? Reducing the constant value in   **O(nd)** is also very helpful  for me.

Comment: Isn't the bottleneck in the memory allocations? Can't you pass pre-allocated arrays to the function?

Comment: You could try calculating `a = alpha/v[j]` and `b = (1-alpha)/w[j]` outside of the second loop and then calculating `pj[i] = a*x_abs[i] + b*x_2[i];` instead. However the compiler might be doing this optimization for you already and the result might be slightly different due to floating point errors

Comment: @Bathsheba I have no constrains on memory usage. Please go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: You could make a third for-loop, just for `x_abs[i] = abs(X[i + jd]);`. The compiler will then use vectorization to speed up the second loop (the one which contains `x_2[i] = ...` etc.).

Comment: @MBo The inner `for (unsigned long i=0; i<d; ++i) {
            x_abs[i] = abs(X[i+jd]); ... etc` should already tell you that the storage is 'vector major' (all components of a vector are stored in consecutive positions)

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: since you have problems related with the performance, the dimension of your vectors is quite large.
If this is the case, then it worth considering "CPU cache locality" - some interesting info on this [in a cppcon14 presentation](https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=2117).

If the data is not available in the CPU caches, then `abs`-ing or squaring it it once available is dwarfed by the time the CPU just wait for the data.

With this is mind, you may want *to try* the following solution (with no warranties that will improve performance - the compiler may actually apply these techniques when optimizing the code)

```
for (unsigned long j=0; j<n; ++j) {
        // use pointer arithmetic - at > -O0 the compiler will do it anyway
        double *start=X+j*d, *end=X+(j+1)*d;

        // this part avoid as much as possible the competition
        // on CPU caches between X and v/w.
        // Don't store the norms in v/w as yet, keep them in registers
        double l1norm=0, l2norm=0;
        for(double *src=start; src!=end; src++) {
            double val=*src;
            l1norm+=abs(src);
            l2norm+= src*src;
        }
        double pl1=alpha/l1norm, pl2=(1-alpha)*l2norm;
        for(double *src=start, *dst=pj; src!=end; src++, dst++) {
          // Yes, recomputing abs/sqr may actually save time by not
          // creating competition on CPU caches with x_abs and x_2
          double val=*src;
          *dst = pl1*abs(val) + pl2*val*val;
        }    
        // functionA(pj){ ... ...}  for subsequent applications

        // Think well if you really need v/w. If you really do,
        // at least there are two values to be sent for storage into memory,
        //meanwhile the CPU can actually load the next vector into cache
        v[j]=l1norm; w[j]=l2norm;
}
// functionB(v, w){ ... ...} for subsequent applications
```